# Why is the gr count 0 in my program output?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm new to R and DM/ML, and I wrote a small program to try out the optim function.

I used optim with SANN method. I defined my own `gr` function and made some config with the `control` parameter.

The problem is that when I print the output, the count of `gr`, which stands for the number of calls to the gr function, is 0, while the number of calls to fn is correct.

Here's my runnable code(I think the cost function is irrevelant so I posted a simple one):

```
people = list('Seymour'='BOS',
'Franny'='DAL',
'Zooey'='CAK',
'Walt'='MIA',
'Buddy'='ORD',
'Les'='OMA')

schedulecost <- function(schedule){
    return(sum(schedule))
}

annealingOptimize <- function(domains, step=1, T=10000,costf=schedulecost){
    solution <- sample(1:9, 2 * length(people), replace=T)
    grFunction <- function(sol){
        index <- sample(c(1:length(domains$Up)), 1, replace=T)
        delta <- as.integer(runif(1,min=-step-1,max=step+1))
        newValue <- sol[index] + delta
        if (newValue > domains$Up[index]){
            newValue <- domains$Up[index]
        }
        if (newValue < domains$Down[index]){
            newValue <- domains$Down[index]
        }
        sol[index] <- newValue
        return(sol)
    }
    values <- optim(solution,costf,gr=grFunction, method='SANN',
            control=list(temp=T, REPORT=1, maxit=200, tmax=10))
    print(values)
    return(values$par)
}
domains <- list(Down=rep(1,length(people) * 2), Up=rep(9, length(people) * 2))
schedule <-annealingOptimize(domains)
```

And the output is:

```
$par
 [1] 2 2 6 2 3 5 5 1 9 1 1 7

$value
[1] 44

$counts
function gradient 
     200       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

In my understanding, the count of `gr` should equal to the count of `fn`, since you need to call the `fn` iff you have a new candidate from a call to `gr`.

Is my understanding incorrect(if yes, what's their relationship) or there's something wrong with my code.

Any one can help ?

Thanks so much !

**Update**:

As @Dwin pointed out, in the help documentation it says: "Method "SANN" ...  uses only function values but is relatively slow. " But in the description of the parameter `gr` it says: "For the "SANN" method it specifies a function to generate a new candidate point. "

If you add some print statement in my `grFunction`, you can see that it actually got called very intensively.

Besides, if the SANN method just use `fn` and doesn't use gr, then what the sentence for `gr` really mean ?

Comment: What am I missing? I do not see any code that would increment an object named "gr" (much less return it to the calling environment.)

Comment: @DWin, the gr is called inside the optim function to generate a new candidate for the cost function, so you can not see it explicitly increased. The same with the fn.

Comment: I did understand that `gr` is a function passed to optim, and now I see that you are talking about $counts[c("function", "gradient"].

Comment: @Dwin, it's not 'I think' there is a count for gr, but it's specified in the documentation of the optim function as part of the return value by optim. See the 'Value' part of this link: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html

Comment: I suspect the clue is in the sentence in the help page that says of the SANN method: " It uses only function values but is relatively slow.

Comment: @DWin, please see my new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating the code in `src/main/optim.c` shows that the SANN method really does call the gradient function (which you have of course confirmed via your print statements), but that it doesn't bother to update the gradient count.  Here's the call to the internal SANN function `samin`:

```
   samin (npar, dpar, &val, fminfn, maxit, tmax, temp, trace, (void *)OS);
        for (i = 0; i < npar; i++)
            REAL(par)[i] = dpar[i] * (OS->parscale[i]);
        fncount = npar > 0 ? maxit : 1;
        grcount = NA_INTEGER;
```

and I can confirm that `samin` calls `genptry`, which calls the gradient function.

This strikes me as a bug (which could be reported to the R development list, or on the R bugs tracker), but a harmless one.  As you point out, presumably the gradient (= candidate point generator) function always gets called exactly the same number of times (OK, give or take one or two during the set-up stage) as the objective function ... (but I understand the confusion when the function doesn't do what it says in the documentation!)

Comment: Thanks Ben. I understand the confusion after I did more test. I think the count for fn and gr may be different for other optim methods other than SANN, so the counter is actually a general counter, not specifically for SANN. As you said, it may be just a harmless bug :)